# AtomicInteger is implemented base on JNI?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, java-native-interface

Soneone told me that [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) is implemented using JNI, so it is much faster than synchonization. Is this true?

Comment: Did they actually say "JNI" or did they say "native code"? There's a big difference.

Comment: JNI is a way of interoperating with *external* native code. In this case I'd expect the code to be part of the JVM, so it doesn't need to go through nearly as many hoops.

Answer (score 7):

It is unlikely to be implemented based on JNI as this would imply significant overhead. Last time I looked the OpenJDK implementation is based on methods in `sun.misc.Unsafe` which are mostly implemented as JVM primitives (method calls that are implemented specially with native code in the JVM).

Comment: +1: I think its called JVM intrinsics. Many "native" methods in Unsafe are effectively inlined when compiled to native code.

Comment: A rather important note is that it is not defined (in the API) to use sun.misc.Unsafe, so other VM's than the Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK may implement AtomicInteger in an entirely different way. It's probably a good idea to use AtomicInteger if you don't have to shoehorn it in, as it is likely to perform well on any VM.

Answer (score 0):

Getting to the point of the question, AtomicInteger does not invoke the lock mechanism of synchronization, so could offer performance benefits in suitable circumstances.